# SqlException when the database is not started but SQL Server is ready for connections

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, exception

I am dealing with quite long delay between "ready for connections" state of SQL Server and the time when my database is started. Sometimes it takes more then 2 minutes. That's reason why I sometimes try to connect to database before it's online. Do you know, how to reduce time between the "ready for connections" and started database? Or how can I determine that the db is online to connect to it from my C# application?

Basically I have some "cache" of connections by connection string. This happens for the first connection of course, so my code for connections quite simple:

```
var result = new SqlConnection();

result.ConnectionString = "some connection string here";

try
{
   result.Open()
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //some logging stuff here
   throw;
}
```

This is the C# exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "XXX" requested by the login. The login failed.

This is the SQL Server log:

> 2014-03-31 08:21:05.65 - SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
>
> 2014-03-31 08:21:09.21 - Recovery completed for database model (database ID 3) in 1 second(s) (analysis 234 ms, redo 0 ms, undo 514 ms.) This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> 2014-03-31 08:21:11.52 - Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
>
> 2014-03-31 08:21:11.52 - Login failed for user 'YYY'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: ]
>
> 2014-03-31 08:21:13.88 - Clearing tempdb database.
>
> 2014-03-31 08:21:21.38 - Recovery completed for database msdb (database ID 4) in 2 second(s) (analysis 327 ms, redo 0 ms, undo 468 ms.) This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> 2014-03-31 08:21:32.98 - Starting up database 'tempdb'.
>
> 2014-03-31 08:21:40.30 - The Service Broker protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
>
> 2014-03-31 08:21:40.41 - The Database Mirroring protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
>
> 2014-03-31 08:21:41.50 - Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> 2014-03-31 08:21:41.52 - Service Broker manager has started.
>
> 2014-03-31 08:23:41.87 - Starting up database 'XXX'.

Comment: Show your code using for connecting to database !!

Comment: Check AutoClose property: `SELECT Name, is_auto_close_on
FROM master.sys.databases`

Comment: AutoClose is disabled as well as mirroring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx), the best practise is to query value of Collation property.

> A database that has just come online is not necessarily ready to accept connections. To identify when a database can accept connections, query the collation_name column of sys.databases or the Collation property of DATABASEPROPERTYEX.

So when the Collation property is not null, the database is ready for connections. The query look like this

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('MyDatabase', 'Collation')
```